# SSL Certificate verify failed Error while performing Requests

Tags: request, windows-10, ssl-certificate

I get this error when I perform a python request for google apis.

```
Error Connecting: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I had this working earlier but my company provided me a new laptop and it started failing since then.

I am running Windows 10 and Python 3.6.6.  It also fails for some other API requests too. The same code works with Ubuntu system and also with `verify=False` (throws warning which is expected.) on Windows 10 system.

I tried installing new requests library also tried installing `-U requests[security]`. Also tried to download and install OpenSSL for Windows. I am not sure if I have to install the google certificate manually because I can access Google Maps in browser.

Any feedback will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this figured out. It was a Bluecoat Proxy Agent which was running in background. Just uninstalled it. Hope it helps someone in the future.